# How to check for any empty text boxes using jquery?

Tags: jquery, forms, jsp

I'm using jQuery v1.11.1 on a jsp page running java 1.76 and I'm trying to just check if any text boxes are empty, if so I want to return false, otherwise return true.  I've seen lots of similar things, but not exactly for what I'm trying.

It's not returning false when it encounters an empty textbox and I'm thinking there is a cleaner way to select this, rather than a loop with my version.  Here is my code:

```
$('input:text').each(function() {
       var element = $(this);

       if(element.val() == '') {
          // isValid = false;
          alert("All the inputs must have values!");
          return false;
       }
    });
```

What should I be using to accomplish this?

Comment: this is the correct way to check all textbox in your page.

please note it check all textbox in your jsp page.

if you want more information please find this JSfiddler

http://jsfiddle.net/L2m4g54j/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and then the `length` property.

```
var emptyTextBox = $('input:text').filter(function() {
   return $(this).val() == '';
});

if(emptyTextBox.length > 0) {
   alert("All the inputs must have values!");
   return false;
}
```